# toISOString not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, datetime, iso

I am creating a new date toISOString -

```
new Date(03-13-2016 00:00).toISOString();
```

This works fine in IE and Chrome however NOT in FireFox.

I have tried to modify the string slightly like -

```
new Date(03-13-2016T00:00:00Z).toISOString();
```

However this also failed. How can I achieve the desired result to work across all browsers?

```
2016-03-13T00:00:00.000Z
```

PS I am aware I start with a string then try and create a string with the `toISOString` - reason being this handles timezone offset to UTC in one line which is required.

Comment: The string you're passing to start with is non-standard, so the browser is free to parse it how it feels.  It seems FireFox feels it can't parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind pulling a library in or need to work with dates more often, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which has some very convenient date and time methods and is cross browser compatible.

Your string could then be converted to an ISO String like:

```
moment('03-13-2016 00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm').format();
```

Comment: Yeh was trying to not pull anything else in however looks like it will be a necessity, i will give your solution a bash and make sure I mark as correct once tested thanks for input.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a string to the `Date` constructor, it internally calls `Date.parse` to attempt to get a valid date from it.  This first checks to see if it is one of [the Date Time formats](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) in the specification.  If not (and both `"03-13-2016 00:00"` and `"03-13-2016T00:00:00Z"` aren't), the [`parse` specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.parse) goes on to say:

> If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats. Unrecognizable Strings or dates containing illegal element values in the format String shall cause Date.parse to return NaN.

In this case, it seems both IE and Chrome have code in place that allows it to be correctly parsed, while Firefox doesn't.  The only way you're really going to fix this is to have a string that conforms to the specification, or to call the constructor with [individual date/time component parts](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms).